# Incredibuild not very fast

Tags: c++, build, build-process, incredibuild

Our project takes a long time to compile, so I'm trying the trial version of Incredibuild.

It is made of a solution of about 50 projects.

The thing is, when I compile with incredibuild it doesn't go much faster, it may even last longer some times ...

Here is a screenshot of the graph produced by incredibuild while build a subproject of the solution and it's dependencies, at times it appears to be doing absolutely nothing :
[image]

The build without incredibuild took 4 minutes, with it here 5 minutes, most often is falls to 3:30 like in the following case, but still with some gaps:
[image]

**Any idea what could cause this to happen?**

note the problem is the same if I build the whole project

btw the red line is cpu usage, green network in, and blue network out, as reported by incredibuild.

**edit:** just to be clear and since some people tend to focus on the low compile time of the examples above instead of trying to give a meaningful answer, a full rebuild of the project takes about 1 hour and half

Comment: Why tag with C++? and I can't read any of these screenshots....

Comment: have you asked the guys at incredibuild?

Comment: There's a difference between being fast and not taking long.

Comment: Define a "long time" Our primary project @ work has some 65 projects and takes less than 5 minutes for a complete rebuild. Perhaps your build architecture needs some TLC.

Comment: I worked on a project that took 2 hours to build due to the level of templating in it... and that was parallel builds...

Comment: 5 minutes is for a **SUBSET** of the project, a full rebuild takes about 1 hour and a half

Comment: @Caribou I tagged C++ because it is a c++ project and it might be a relevant information for people willing to answer.

Comment: Given that it is C++ code being built, I think the C++ tag is relevant. The performance of a build system depends on what is being built, after all. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing you can do is to send your log file to the IncrediBuild support team at support@incredibuild.com

In order to extract the log file, please follow the following instructions:

1. Set your Agent's logging level to "Extended" (right click the IncrediBuild tray icon->Agent Settings->"Agent|General" page).
2. Run your build.
3. Double-click the IncrediBuild tray-icon to open the Build Monitor.
4. Select "File->Save Monitor File As..." to save the build progress file and attach the file to your reply.
5. Restore your logging level back to "Minimal".

Please mention in your email that Dori referred you to the support department.

Thanks,
The IncrediBuild Team.

Comment: How will you analyse the log file? Could you build that analysis into the software?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, we have many system logs we write into the log file. Unfortunately we can't build this into the software due to the fact that it will reveal some of our intellectual property.